# Data cleaning - shifting data between columns

Tags: r, dplyr

With example dataframe below, I'm looking for a way to shift values, starting at column v2, to the right, while replacing gaps with zeros, if column v9 contains 'a'.

```
set.seed(0)
df <- matrix(sample(c("a", 1:3), 100, replace = TRUE), nrow=10) 
colnames(df) <- c(paste0("v", 1:10))
df <- as_tibble(df)
df$v11 <- 0

# A tibble: 10 x 11
      v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7    v8    v9   v10   v11
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1     3     a     3     1     1     2     1     3     3     a     0
 2     1     a     3     1     3     1     3     1     1     a     0
 3     1     a     a     2     2     3     1     3     2     a     0
 4     2     2     2     1     3     1     1     1     1     2     0
 5     3     1     a     a     2     a     1     1     1     3     0
 6     a     3     1     3     2     a     2     1     3     3     0
 7     3     1     1     2     3     a     1     3     a     3     0
 8     3     2     a     3     a     1     1     3     2     1     0
 9     2     3     1     a     1     2     3     1     a     1     0
10     2     1     3     2     2     2     a     3     a     3     0
```

so the resulting dataframe would be (rows 7, 9, 10 shifted):

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v9  v10 v11
1   3   a   3   1   1   2   1   3   3   a   0
2   1   a   3   1   3   1   3   1   1   a   0
3   1   a   a   2   2   3   1   3   2   a   0
4   2   2   2   1   3   1   1   1   1   2   0
5   3   1   a   a   2   a   1   1   1   3   0
6   a   3   1   3   2   a   2   1   3   3   0
7   3   0   1   1   2   3   a   1   3   a   3
8   3   2   a   3   a   1   1   3   2   1   0
9   2   0   3   1   a   1   2   3   1   a   1
10  2   0   1   3   2   2   2   a   3   a   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, getting all the rows where `v9`column contains 'a'.

```
req_rows <- which(df$v9 == "a")
req_rows
[1]  7  9 10
```

**Second**, shifting cells to right in desired locations

```
df[req_rows,2:length(df)] <- df[req_rows,1:length(df)-1]
> df
# A tibble: 10 × 11
      v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7    v8    v9   v10   v11
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1      3     a     3     1     1     2     1     3     3     a     0
2      1     a     3     1     3     1     3     1     1     a     0
3      1     a     a     2     2     3     1     3     2     a     0
4      2     2     2     1     3     1     1     1     1     2     0
5      3     1     a     a     2     a     1     1     1     3     0
6      a     3     1     3     2     a     2     1     3     3     0
7      3     3     1     1     2     3     a     1     3     a     3
8      3     2     a     3     a     1     1     3     2     1     0
9      2     2     3     1     a     1     2     3     1     a     1
10     2     2     1     3     2     2     2     a     3     a     3
```

**Third**, replacing gaps with zeros.

```
df$v2[req_rows] <- 0
```

which results in

```
> df
# A tibble: 10 × 11
      v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7    v8    v9   v10   v11
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1      3     a     3     1     1     2     1     3     3     a     0
2      1     a     3     1     3     1     3     1     1     a     0
3      1     a     a     2     2     3     1     3     2     a     0
4      2     2     2     1     3     1     1     1     1     2     0
5      3     1     a     a     2     a     1     1     1     3     0
6      a     3     1     3     2     a     2     1     3     3     0
7      3     0     1     1     2     3     a     1     3     a     3
8      3     2     a     3     a     1     1     3     2     1     0
9      2     0     3     1     a     1     2     3     1     a     1
10     2     0     1     3     2     2     2     a     3     a     3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df$v9=='a',paste('v',2:11,sep = "")] <-
                                    df%>%
                                    select(v2:v11)%>%
                                     filter(v9=='a')%>%
                                      t()%>%
                                    lag(default = 0)%>%
                                       t()%>%
                                      as_tibble()
```